# npm link removes child dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-link

I am trying to do local development of an NPM package and test it in a package which depends on it. I'm using NPM (7.5.3) and specifically `npm link` for this but running into a problem with the chain of dependencies.

The child package has dependencies, these are all added to the parent's node_modules folder when using `npm install "git+https://github.com/name/child_package"`. But when I `npm link` that module:

```sh
cd child_package
npm link
cd ../parent_package
npm link child_package
```

With the last command run (`npm link child_package`), all of the dependencies for `child_package` which were in the node_modules of `parent_package` are removed. NPM reporting:

> removed 60 packages, changed 1 package, and audited 231 packages in 1s

At which point all the compilation in the parent package fails due to the missing deps. It finds the child_package, which is symlinked as expected, but dependency defined in child_package of "gsap" has now been removed.

If I reinstall it using `npm install "git+https://github.com/name/child_package"` it will add the deps back into the node_modules folder of the parent project.

Comment: Yup, happening to me too. This is supremely annoying.

Comment: Checkout Lerna https://github.com/lerna/lerna if you haven't already. It will allow you to bootstrap packages - e.g. install the child_package's dependencies and then the parent. If the child is also available locally. You can then simply do an npm link without blowing away anyones dependencies

Comment: I stumbled upon [`yalc`](https://github.com/wclr/yalc) which provides the same utility but without this annoying bug. Saved me a headache, give it a shot :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a [behavior introduced in npm V7 +](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2339) .

The only reasonable "workaround" i have found is to go back to npm 6 (`npm install -g npm@6`).

Another "workaround" is to `npm install --no-save ../../my-local-module` but to reflect changes to the local module you will need to delete it from node_modules and reinstall again. Kind of lame....

Answer (score 1):

try to do the following:

```
cd child_package
npm install
```

that will install child dependencies to directory of child package

personally I hate **npm link** and always use **npm publish** (use version number like 1.0.0-preview.1 for your child package and remove '-preview.Number' when you are done)

Comment: Tried this, doesn't work. When I try to run the main project (that i linked the package into) it still complains of the missing deps. The goal with link to is develop on the child package, so not sure how publish would be a better alternative thank link?